# Can't connect to GCP VM website with external IP

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

Trying to connect to my django website (from the browser) that's stored on the GCP virtual machine.
Everything works fine if I'm accessing it internally using internal IP or localhost.

However, I can't access website with external IP.
No logs in django that would say someone trying to access if I'm trying with external IP.

I have http, https traffic enabled on instance.

Firewall rule to allow port 80:

[image]

Here is Test-Net results.

[image]

Searched the web for answers but nothing looks wrong in my settings..
Any ideas would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

1. Do not create or change egress rules unless you know exactly what they do. They are not necessary for ingress rules (VPC Firewalls automatically allow return traffic):

**I've changed all firewall rules back how they were so now only port 80 is allowed.**

2. You have an ingress rule for the target http-server. Is that target flag set on the VM instance?

[image]

3. What is the output from sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN? Your Django server must be listening on 0.0.0.0.0 instead of localhost.

I have 0.0.0.0 with port 80 at django terminal.
[image]
I use windows 2016 server so don't know the powershell function that would display what you asked for.
Here is netstat listening ports for django.

[image]

Comment: [Firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#internet_access_reqs) must allow egress traffic from the instance. Unless overridden by a higher priority rule, the implied allow rule for egress traffic permits outbound traffic from all instances. Check whether the egress is allowed or not.

Comment: @Srividya, No, i don't have any egress rules here. Only ingress. So you saying all i have to do is create new rule for target http-server port 80 just with egress option?
I will try this and come back to you.

Comment: @Srividya, This didn't help.. Created new firewall rule for egress allow ports 5432, 8000 and ip ranges 0.0.0.0/0 and still can't connect..

Comment: How did you bind your Django app? Did you use 127.0.0.1? If that's the case change it to 0.0.0.0 on port 80

Comment: @FerreginaPelona, It was already 0.0.0.0:80 , still can't connect.. Don't understand why, as i can ping the address but looks like port is not open even if i allowed http , http, all ports open in controls..

Comment: Edit your question with details. 1) Do not create or change egress rules unless you know exactly what they do. They are not necessary for ingress rules (VPC Firewalls automatically allow return traffic). 2) You have an ingress rule for the target **http-server**. Is that target flag set on the VM instance? 3) What is the output from **sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN**? Your Django server must be listening on **0.0.0.0.0** instead of **localhost**.

Comment: @JohnHanley, please see updated question.

Comment: @Stag, Can you curl the website from the terminal? e.g. **curl localhost** By using the curl command you will be able to determine that the webserver is in fact alive and ready for connections to minimize the troubleshooting time.

Comment: @Stag, Have you tried the curl command? If yes, can you please post the output or if your issue got resolved can you please post your resolution steps.